# Text/Voice/Category channel remove all overwrite permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Reset all permissions set for the channel. I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `channel.lockPermissions()` its will reset all channel permissions, so channel will get parent permissions.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  // If the message is "ping"
  if (message.content === 'rest') {
    // Send "pong" to the same channel
    targetChannel = message.guild.channels.get('PLACEE ID HERE')
    if (targetChannel) targetChannel.lockPermissions()
  }
});
```